# Automatically advancing to the next screen after processing completion

Tags: task-completion, actions

I have a screen that downloads videos from a website to the users' disk. Once it has completed  downloading should I automatically switch to a screen that displays the videos or should I just enable a Next button so that the user can click it on their own time?

Currently after the download has finished, the progress bar is full, and the Next button is enabled. See the image below.

[image]

Comment: You should have enough reputation to post images now if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd display the video - but don't automatically play it.

This is immediate feedback that the download has completed. Just showing a "Next" button could imply that the download failed in some way.